# Django - Save a Excel file to a model's FileFild

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to save a file in my excel_file field but i have this error :

 **'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 15: invalid start byte**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    excel_file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload', blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try : 
            myFile = open('excel_file.xlsx', 'r')
            name = "new_test.xlsx"
            self.excel_file.save(name, File(myFile))
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not open your file in *binary* mode, hence the error:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    excel_file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload', blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try :
            #                  binary mode ↓
            with open('excel_file.xlsx', 'rb') as myFile:
                name = 'new_test.xlsx'
                self.excel_file.save(name, File(myFile), save=False)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Here the [**`save=False`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) will prevent that saving the excel file will result in calling the `save` method of the model again, and thus leads to infinite recursion.

---

> **Note**: Please do not make use of a *blanket except*: try to limit exception handling to
> specific exceptions. Other exceptions should not be catched, but handled by the
> code flow that called the subroutine. By making use of `except`, you basically
> will stop *any* exception, but that is often *not* a good idea, since the caller
> thus assumes that the call succeeded.

Comment: Thanks, but Now i have an other error : maximum recursion depth exceeded Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. And that created a folder with many file not a new Excel file with new_test.xlsx name

Comment: @alpha: ys, that is because `self.excel_file.save` will trigger the `save` of the `Model` of course.

Comment: @alpha: and the `open(...)` will create a copy of the file, since later it is possible that you aim to update the file, and thus these should be independent from each other.

Comment: @alpha: you can omit the recursion with: `self.excel_file.save(name, File(myFile), save=False)`